# Create CSS-sprite of 1000 images using PHP and XML

Tags: php, xml, sprite

I have a XML file with approximately 1000 image-urls. I want to create a sprite of all the images using PHP.

- The XML file is about 30 MB in size
- The images are about 15kb in size

**How can I get it done?**

Here is my code (I get Fatal error: Allowed memory size ...):

```
<?php

$dest              = imagecreatefromjpeg('15000x2000.jpg');
$increasing_width  = 0;
$increasing_height = 0;

$xmldata = '1000-images.xml';

$open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');

$content = stream_get_contents($open);

fclose($open);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//image') as $image) {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('test/' . $image->picture->attributes() . '.jpg');

    if ($increasing_width == '15000') {
        $increasing_width = '0';
        $increasing_height += 200;
    }

    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, $increasing_width, $increasing_height, 0, 0, 150, 200, 100);

}

imagejpeg($dest, '15000x2000.jpg');

?>
```

Comment: Allocate more memory? Sounds like it's going to be a ginormous image (pixel wise), which will need a metric ton of memory.

Comment: I've got two questions: why do you compare numbers with strings and how much is `allowed memory size` actually?

Comment: Two suggestions come in mind: Either increase the memory_limit directive in your php.ini or use the ImageMagick (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library instead of gd2

Comment: One more question: Do you get the fatal error when parsing the XML or while creating the image ?

Comment: While images are not big, the reason is that now your script reads whole xml and puts it in array (almost the same size as xml itself), so reading it line by line will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for all comments! Will try to change memory limit... Sorry for giving a messy example with strings... Strangly I get the error when parsing the XML, but it works if I just echo the image names instead of creating the sprite.

Comment: Thanks PLB. Would you like to show me an example? (I am not very good at PHP)

Comment: by the way, in normal use cases such a big sprite picture will have only negative effects on performance !

Comment: Thanks Panique. I turned your comment into a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395911/lazy-load-or-huge-css-sprite-9mb-in-size

Answer (score 1):

You will need to increase the **[memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).**

Insert into the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); # Default: 128M
```

*“Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1. ”* — php.net

If you get a timeout after there is enough memory, you will need to increase the **[max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)**.

Insert into the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30); # Default 30
```

*When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.* — php.net